# Differnce between a function and a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

What is the difference between a function and a sequence? I have googled it but I have not found any solid answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is a mapping or function from the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

For example, $\{x_n\}=\sqrt{n+1}$. Here, $n$ takes values which are natural numbers while the function $\{x_n\}$ takes real values.

If you have a hard time believing this, check this [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Formal_definition).

Comment: In other words, sequences are just a special kind of function with domain $\Bbb N$?

Comment: so what's a function then?

Comment: @pjs36 Yes, truly.

Comment: From your definition, it looks like a sequence is a special case of a function.

Comment: Please check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Formal_definition

Comment: @Aniket thanks.

Comment: Not to give you a hard time, but the link contradicts your answer.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod Can you justify how?

Comment: Generally an infinite sequence is a function whose domain is N. The members of the range can be anything .

Comment: Formally, a sequence maps from a _subset_ of the natural numbers to a real, a complex, a topo space, a vector, a matrix, is just about any other kind of mathematical object, not only a real. A very common type of sequence is a sequence of functions.